# How to add string in the middle of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a solution that **doesn't** involve an .apply or lambda function that loops through the list and ads the string at desired index. I have a column like this with many entries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-"], columns=["position"])

    position
0   1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-
```

I'd like:

```
    position
0   chr1:77631829:-:chr1:77641672:-
```

So insert "chr" at beginning and after third colon `:`

I would have thought something like this would do, but insert hasn't been implemented in series:

```
"chr" + df["position"].str.split(":").insert(3, "chr").str.join(":")
```

This does it, but looks inefficient:

```
"chr" + df["position"].str.split(":").str[:3].str.join(":") + "chr" + df["position"].str.split(":").str[3:].str.join(":")
```

Comment: If you are absolutely sure about your format, then you can try `'chr' + df['position'].str.replace('-:', '-:chr')`

Comment: @RaunaqJain Post it as a solution so that it helps for other who refer this question.

Comment: It wasn't actually a solution but a hack, so I didn't post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use split by `3` value of `:`, then extract head and tail of lists - join head, add `ch` to tail, prepend `ch` and last append to list `L`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-","1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-"], 
                  columns=["position"])
print (df)
                    position
0  1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-
1  1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-

L = []
for x in df["position"]:
    *i, j = x.split(':', 3)
    L.append(("chr" + ':'.join(i) + "chr" + j))

df['new'] = L
print (df)
                    position                             new
0  1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-  chr1:77631829:-chr1:77641672:-
1  1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-  chr1:77631829:-chr1:77641672:-
```

Hack solution with comments:

```
'chr' + df['position'].str.replace('-:', '-:chr')
```

Faster with list comprehension and f-strings:

```
df['new'] = [f"ch{x.replace('-:', '-:chr')}" for x in df['position']]
```

**Performance**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-","1:77631829:-:1:77641672:-"], 
                  columns=["position"])

#[20000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [226]: %%timeit
     ...: L = []
     ...: for x in df["position"]:
     ...:     *i, j = x.split(':', 3)
     ...:     L.append(("chr" + ':'.join(i) + "chr" + j))
     ...: 
     ...: df['new1'] = L
     ...: 
18.9 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [227]: %%timeit
     ...: df['new2'] = "chr" + df["position"].str.split(":").str[:3].str.join(":") + "chr" + df["position"].str.split(":").str[3:].str.join(":")
     ...: 
50.8 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [228]: %%timeit
     ...: df['new3'] = 'chr' + df['position'].str.replace('-:', '-:chr')
     ...: 
21.5 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [229]: %%timeit
     ...: df['new4'] = [f"ch{x.replace('-:', '-:chr')}" for x in df['position']]
     ...: 
8.59 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Just a tiny nitpicking: OP does not want to use `apply` or `lambda` or loops. If possible compare your solution with `'chr' + df['position'].str.replace('-:', '-:chr')` so that he gets the Idea which is fast and better.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - Yes, but loops with text pure python function are faster like non loops pandas textx `str` functions.